# AttributeError: 'DataFrame' object has no attribute 'group'

Tags: python, python-3.x, excel, pandas, dataframe

I'm clueless about this error.
First I try

```
import pandas as pd
datafile = "E:\...\DPA.xlsx"
data = pd.read_excel(datafile)
data
```

And everything is fine. Then...

```
data.boxplot('DPA', by='Liga', figsize=(12, 8))
```

Everything keeps going fine. then...

```
ctrl = data['DPA'][data.group == 'PremierLeague']

grps = pd.unique(data.group.values)
d_data = {grp:data['DPA'][data.group == grp] for grp in grps}

k = len(pd.unique(data.group))  # number of conditions
N = len(data.values)  # conditions times participants
n = data.groupby('Liga').size()[0] #Participants in each condition
```

And here is when I get this error:

```
AttributeError: 'DataFrame' object has no attribute 'group'
```

Any ideas? I'm following this steps https://www.marsja.se/four-ways-to-conduct-one-way-anovas-using-python/ to make an ANOVA.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

`DataFrame` has no attribute `group`. However, it is possible to access data in a column in your dataframe with the same syntax used to access attributes and methods, i.e. if you have a column `col`, you may access the series related to this column through

```
df.col
```

What happened here is that your data is probably different from what she used in the tutorial. Or at least, the columns she has are different than the columns you have.

To solve that problem, you can either (I) simply rename your columns to match the columns from the tutorial or (II) replace `data.group` with the corresponding column name that you have in your `df`

Comment: in this case that would be data[data.group == 'PremierLeague']